# Google sheet script to update cell value in selected row in another sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need to get script that updates values in another spreadsheet from row marked with checkbox to row with common ID as shown in picture attached:

[image]

Once Ann's work is done I select row 6 in blue spreadsheet and click on icon to trigger the script. The script finds desired row with Ann's work in yellow spreadsheet and changes status to "DONE".

I have tried to work with code I found in another topic but it was created for onedit function and with little bit different functionality. So far I failed.

Script below was meant to work with single selected row but ideal script would deal with multiple selected rows at once. Can you help?

```
function valueupdate(e) {
  const { range } = e;
  const sheet = range.getSheet();
  if (sheet.getSheetName() != "bluetab" && col === 1 && row > 2 && sheet.getRange(row, 1).getValues() == true || range.columnStart != 1) return; // Modified
  const [id] = range.offset(0, 1).getDisplayValues()[0]; // Modified
  //Browser.msgBox([id, , status])
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('xxxxx-yellowtab-spreadsheet-id-xxxxx'); // Please set your Spreadsheet ID of destination spreadsheet.
  const dstSheet = ss.getSheetByName("yellowtab");
  const r = dstSheet.getRange("b2:b" + dstSheet.getLastRow()).createTextFinder(id).matchEntireCell(true).findNext();
  if (!r) return;
  r.offset(0, 1).setValue("DONE");
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- In your script, `col` and `row` are not declared.

  - I think that the reason for your current issue might be due to this.
- `if (sheet.getSheetName() != "bluetab" && col === 1 && row > 2 && sheet.getRange(row, 1).getValues() == true || range.columnStart != 1) return;` is required to be modified.
- From your showing image, it seems that you wanted to retrieve the value from column "C" of `bluetab` sheet. But, in your script, column "B" is used by `range.offset(0, 1).getDisplayValues()[0];`.
- - From your showing image, it seems that you wanted to put the value to column "A". But, in your script, column "B" is used by `r.offset(0, 1).setValue("DONE");`.

When these points are reflected in your script, how about the following modified script?

#### Modified script:

Please set your destination Spreadsheet ID to `###` of `const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('###');`. And, please install the OnEdit trigger to the function of `valueupdate`.

```js
function valueupdate(e) {
  const { range } = e;
  const sheet = range.getSheet();
  if (sheet.getSheetName() != "bluetab" || range.columnStart != 1 || range.rowStart <= 2 || !range.isChecked()) return;
  const id = range.offset(0, 2).getDisplayValue();
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('###');
  const dstSheet = ss.getSheetByName("yellowtab");
  const r = dstSheet.getRange("B2:B" + dstSheet.getLastRow()).createTextFinder(id).matchEntireCell(true).findNext();
  if (!r) return;
  r.offset(0, -1).setValue("DONE");
}
```

- In this modified script, when the checkbox of column "A" of "bluetab" sheet is checked, the ID is retrieved from column "C". And, the ID is searched from the destination sheet of "yellowtab", and when the ID is found, `DONE` is put to column "A".

#### References:

- [Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)
- [Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)

### Added:

From your following reply,

> It works good the way you describe it but I need to have it triggered manually not with OnEdit.

In this case, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```js
function sample() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const srcSheet = ss.getSheetByName("bluetab");
  const dstSheet = ss.getSheetByName("yellowtab");
  const obj = Object.fromEntries(srcSheet.getRange("A3:C" + srcSheet.getLastRow()).getValues().map(([a, , c]) => [c, a]));
  const dstRange = dstSheet.getRange("A3:B" + dstSheet.getLastRow());
  const values = dstRange.getValues().map(([, b]) => [obj[b] || null, b]);
  dstRange.setValues(values);
}
```

- When this script is run, the values are retrieved from "bluetab" sheet, and check the checkboxes of column "A". And, the new value is put to "yellowtab" sheet by the IDs of the checked checkboxes.
- In this script, the old value of column "A" of "yellowtab" sheet is cleared. But, if you want to leave the old value, please modify it as follows.

  - From

    ```
      const values = dstRange.getValues().map(([, b]) => [obj[b] || null, b]);
    ```
  - To

    ```
      const values = dstRange.getValues().map(([a, b]) => [obj[b] || a, b]);
    ```

Comment: Thank you for help. It works good the way you describe it but I need to have it triggered manually not with OnEdit. Can you help?

Comment: @Michał Kostrzewa Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. About `It works good the way you describe it but I need to have it triggered manually not with OnEdit. Can you help?`, I added one more sample script. Please confirm it.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not able to understand mechanism of second script so I will focus on first one. What if I would like to add more conditions "if"? If column A "checked" set status to "DONE" but if column A is "!!!"  set status to "DELAYED"?

Comment: @Michał Kostrzewa Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your current issue from `Unfortunately I'm not able to understand mechanism of second script so I will focus on first one. What if I would like to add more conditions "if"? If column A "checked" set status to "DONE" but if column A is "!!!" set status to "DELAYED"? `. Can I ask you about the detail of your current issue?

Comment: I need to modify to get 2 conditions - "ischecked" or "!!!"

if (sheet.getSheetName() != "bluetab" || range.columnStart != 1 || range.rowStart <= 2 || !range.isChecked()) return;
.
.
r.offset(0, -1).setValue("DONE");

else

if (sheet.getSheetName() != "bluetab" || range.columnStart != 1 || range.rowStart <= 2 || !range.value == '!!!') return;
.
.
.
r.offset(0, -1).setValue("DELAYED");

Comment: @Michał Kostrzewa Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, from your reply, I cannot still understand your current issue. Can I ask you about the detail of your current issue? And, in your question, `DONE` is used. But, in your reply, `DONE` and `DELAYED` are used. You have changed your question. I'm confused about your situation. I apologize for my very poor English skill, again.